# Avoiding overlapping tuples in python while appending to a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a pattern matching and appending their indices into a list. While appending, i would like to avoid appending any overlapping indices already in the list. I have an example code below that i worked out but do not print exactly what i require.

```
import re
pat_list=[]
for i in ['ALA', 'AL', 'LA']:
  for p in re.finditer(i, 'MALAYALAM'):
      if p:
         print (i, p.span())
         if len(pat_list)==0:
            pat_list.append(p.span())
        
         print ('LIST',pat_list)
         if len(pat_list) >0:
            res=[(idx[0], idx[1]) for idx in pat_list if not p.span()[0] >= idx[0] and 
            p.span()[0]<= idx[1] or p.span()[1] >= idx[0] and p.span()[1]<= idx[1] ]
            
            print ('RES',res)
```

What i expect to have in the list is [(1,4), (5,8)] and the rest of the indices should not be added.
For any suggestion or help, i will be very grateful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most optimized code. But I've implemented it using set so that it can be easily understood what I'm trying to do.

```
word = 'MALAYALAM'
to_find = ['ALA', 'AL', 'LA']
indices = []

# I am creating list of sets to use the issubset method
for piece in to_find:
    for found in re.finditer(piece, word):
        indices.append(set(range(found.start(), found.end() + 1)))
# indices: [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 4}, {6, 7, 8}]

non_overlap = []
for left in indices:
    for right in indices:
        is_subset = False
        if left==right:
            continue
        if left.issubset(right):
            is_subset = True
            break
    # If left is the super-set. i.e. independent of other set
    if not is_subset:
        non_overlap.append((min(left), max(left)))
# non_overlap: [(1, 4), (5, 8)]
```

There are definately efficient methods out there. But this is one of the easiest solutions.

Comment: Thank you Pax! This prints the result i wanted. I will go through your method.